# Javascript library in gwt

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

How to aadd javscript library from file to gwt?

I tried:

- `ScriptInjector` - exception is thrown: `onModuleLoad()` threw an exception

  Exception while loading module modue.name. See Development Mode for details.
  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
      at ...
- own script injector ([source](http://simon.pamies.de/archives/194))

  Problem: content of the library is added to the source code, but cannot be accessible any part of the source code.

Can sb give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Solution for your problem with the 2nd option (own script injector)

> Problem: content of the library is added to the source code, but cannot be accessible any part of the source code.

You have to use [JSNI](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html) to be able to use the javascript-methods of the added library in gwt.

Here is a little example for executing a javascript-method from java:

Let's say the added javascript-library contains this method:

```
function say(message) {
    window.alert(message);
}
```

Create a java class JavascriptLibrary.java:

```
public final class JavascriptLibrary {

    public static native void sayJava(String message) /*-{
        $wnd.say(message);
    }-*/;

}
```

Now you can execute this method with `JavascriptLibrary.sayJava("Hello");`

Comment: I have ready external library and by delegates I want to invoke methods. How to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure, what you mean by that. Is this a question about a specific method of the library or do you still have problems with executing any of the javascript-methods via JSNI?

Comment: I did this, but a bit tricky. Solution: `interface MyLibraryBundle extends ClientBundle {

    @Source("mylibrary.js")
    TextResource MyLibraryJS();
}`

Comment: Then I load content of the library with ScriptInjecotr.

Comment: Ok, the library is ready for use then. Now you have to write the JSNI methods, which invoke the relevant javascript (as i mentioned in my answer). More info about how to use JSNI: [JSNI doc](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html).